# Why delete unused objects but bucket object size not reduce

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to reduce bucket size by deleting unused objects but object size not reduce.
I use ways as:

1. gsutil -m rm gs://{Bucket Name}/**
2. Delete Object via Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 library.

What's is best way for this?

Regards.

Comment: Is versioning enabled? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist yes, we have enable versioning for every bucket. I tried to disable bucket after deleting but object size isn't reduce. Thank you for supporting!!!

Comment: I use "-r" option to delete and object size reduced as " gsutil rm -r gs://<bucket_name>/<object>"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to delete object from your bucket:

```
   gsutil rm gs://<bucket_name>/<object>
```

You can refer the below public link for further clarification:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#console

Note: If you have to delete a large number of objects in your buckets, avoid using gsutil, as the operation takes a long time to complete. Instead, use the Cloud Console or Object Lifecycle Management.

Also, you can assign a lifecycle management configuration to a bucket. The configuration contains a set of rules which apply to current and future objects in the bucket. When an object meets the criteria of one of the rules, Cloud Storage automatically performs a specified action on the object. Here are some example use cases:

- Downgrade the storage class of objects older than 365 days to
  Coldline Storage.
- Delete objects created before <specify_date>
- Keep only the 3 most recent versions of each object in a bucket with
  versioning enabled.

Please refer the below link for further information on lifecycle management config:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Comment: Thank you for supporting!!! Currently, I use gsutil command line to delete.

Comment: I use "-r" option to delete and object size reduced as " gsutil rm -r gs://<bucket_name>/<object>"